# object array into action sheet

Tags: ios, swift

i have following object array `var items = [place]()` which contain values like `name` and `image`. however i want to add all the names into an `actionsheet`. however i can't seem to figure out how to add all the names into the `row` section and still being able to return that specific object for later.

```
  ActionSheetStringPicker.showPickerWithTitle("Multiple String Picker", rows:
            ["One", "Two", "A lot"],
            initialSelection: 1, doneBlock: {
                picker, values, indexes in

                print("values = \(values)")
                print("indexes = \(indexes)")
                print("picker = \(picker)")
                return
            }, cancelBlock: {
                ActionMultipleStringCancelBlock in return
            }, origin: self.tableView)
```

Comment: To clarify - you want the action sheet to show a list of names that come from an array of place type objects that have a 'name' property?

Comment: also - if you have a question using a third party thing make sure you link to it so folks can find it to see any related docs